# How to get page extension with js

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get the current page format? I mean, if im in

```
abc.com/index.html
```

How could I get that the page is on index.html instead for example index.jsx / index.php?
I could try to split the URL after the '.', but if the link is on the index it wont show.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: After you do the split, you get an array, just look for the last one

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @YosiLeibman It doesnt work, as previously stated splitting the URL just takes everything before and after that character, but if im on abc.com then you wont get any index.html string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

If you ask the server for the resource at `/` then you get the resource at `/`.

The server won't tell you if it generated it from a file called `index.html` or `index.php` or `default.php` or some logic internal to the server which doesn't involve loading a specific file at all.